# How to know the bitrate used for each codec in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, codec

I can see all available codecs in asterisk with

```
astrisk -rx "core show codecs"
```

Where I can find the related bitrate of each codec?

Are there an asterisk comand for that?

Comment: I hihgly recommend you read book. Asterisk have no any command for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this web app to calculate the bandwidth for various codecs:
[Codecs Bandwidth Calculator](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tools/bandwidth_calculator.php)
Aloso this is a quick introduction about some common Codecs:
[Codec Summary from 3CX](http://www.en.voipforo.com/codec/codecs.php)

Comment: choukran wa baraka allah fik. I m looking to get the values with a command in order to display to the user via tr-069/cwmp protocol. SO the Codec Bandwith Calculator does not is not what I m looking for.

Comment: tell me if i am wrong . you want asterisk to tell you about active calls's related RTP bandwidth consumption? if so unfortunately you need a third party to do this for you as there is nothing such this in asterisk